# В режиме терминала линукса не отображается кириллица

Tags: linux, консоль

Почему в режиме терминала линукса (`Kali Linux`) не отображаются символы кириллицы?
Можно ли и как сделать так, чтобы они отображались?

Для примера я ввёл команду `echo Привет, мир!`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
Вывод `locale`:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**UPD1:**
Перепробовал всё из вопросов выше и ответа ниже: в одних случаях у меня просто нет определённого файла (видимо, другой дистрибутив), в других просто ничего не работает. Шрифты устанавливал и менял, конфигурировал консоль несколько раз, перезагружал компьютер. Ничего не работает. Шрифт в режиме терминала не меняется.

Comment: Покажите вывод `locale`. Ну и неплохо бы увидеть какой шрифт вы грузите для консоли (подсказка: самым популярным был latarcyrheb-sun16 <s>[не помню точное название, гуглите]</s> https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/NewDefaultConsoleFont).

Comment: @0andriy добавил вывод `locale`, а вот, как посмотреть шрифт, я не нашёл.

Comment: `cyr`? ........

Comment: @donRumata а вот `cyr` как-то прошёл мимо меня. Спасибо, что указали на него, с ним всё получилось, вот только после перезагрузки и ввода той же самой команды терминал стал отказываться принимать сигналы от клавиатуры. А после второй перезагрузки и ввода той же команды, всё стало опять нормально.

Comment: В `~/.bashrc` запихни.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала читаете здесь https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77049/how-do-i-change-the-screen-font-size-when-using-a-virtual-console

и узнаете, что нужно отредактировать файл /etc/default/console-setup и "угадать шрифт".

вроде вот такое

```
CODESET="CyrSlav"
FONTFACE="Terminus"
FONTSIZE="8x16"
```

должно быть нормально.

Потом запустить "реконфигурацию"

```
sudo service console-setup restart
```

детали можно посмотреть ещё здесь

- https://mnorin.com/console-cyrillic-i-systemd-v-debian.html
- https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/13535609